# chrome plugin for using proxy service?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, google-chrome-extensions

I want to view certain websites, travelling through proxies?
Does such a google chrome plugin exist where I can just go through proxy with one click for a certain webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension which you can install to enjoy the fastest proxies on internet :

[Proxy List](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omihnninlhneakfglooiofgdbpmnhjgn)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using [Proxy Switchy!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj?hl=en) ? it seems that [FoxyProxy](http://getfoxyproxy.org) is now available for Google Chrome as well.